# Can you get a return URL by GET in JQuery or PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, twitch, twitch-api

Is it possible to code up a way where the code loads the specific URL and then gets the URL that is returned. For example, when I load this URL https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/authorize?client_id=8g11d1v5x70s2ql86wyownczj6hfc0&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FSocialMediaSite%2FSite%2FHome&response_type=code&scope=user%3Aread%3Aemail&state=b5dcc70324892f0d3987936f9332d811

The URL changes to http://localhost/SocialMediaSite/Site/Home?code=kgegrwigrj5i8mm2vdktwstrbmwivg&scope=user%3Aread%3Aemail&state=742a4bf34bea19022074f92680966cc3

This is because twitch is running the api and giving back the return url as the result to that page. But is there a way to do this automatically?
I tried

```
if($('.LoadStreamers').length){

 $.get('../Admin/TwitchAPI/getFollowers.php',function(data){

    console.log(data);
    $.get(data,function (data2){
        console.log(data2);
    })

 })
```

}

and the result i get is

```
  https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/authorize?client_id=8g11d1v5x70s2ql86wyownczj6hfc0&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FSocialMediaSite%2FSite%2FHome&response_type=code&scope=user%3Aread%3Aemail&state=b5dcc70324892f0d3987936f9332d811
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.twitch.tv/login?client_id=8g11d1v5x70s2ql86wyownczj6hfc0&redirect_params=client_id%3D8g11d1v5x70s2ql86wyownczj6hfc0%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FSocialMediaSite%252FSite%252FHome%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Duser%253Aread%253Aemail%26state%3Db5dcc70324892f0d3987936f9332d811' (redirected from 'https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/authorize?client_id=8g11d1v5x70s2ql86wyownczj6hfc0&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FSocialMediaSite%2FSite%2FHome&response_type=code&scope=user%3Aread%3Aemail&state=b5dcc70324892f0d3987936f9332d811') 
from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
jquery.min.js:4 GET https://www.twitch.tv/login?client_id=8g11d1v5x70s2ql86wyownczj6hfc0&redirect_params=client_id%3D8g11d1v5x70s2ql86wyownczj6hfc0%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FSocialMediaSite%252FSite%252FHome%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Duser%253Aread%253Aemail%26state%3Db5dcc70324892f0d3987936f9332d811 net::ERR_FAILED
```

Comment: No, that would be insecure. Twitch specifically designed so that you can't visit a webpage and have it automatically use your own account for whatever. Not only this would be insecure, the user would feel like their privacy was violated.

Comment: @JonathanRosa i figured it out. I have it so a user connects their twitch account and it saves the accesstoken because the user allows the information to be collected. Using this I was able to do it with my call function to my twitch api.